# Ajax - GET method doesn't send params

Tags: javascript, node.js, ajax, get, routes

Here's my request:

```
var xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
xhttp.open("GET", "/api/registerRequest?user=user", true);
xhttp.send();
```

And here's the request being handled:

```
var express = require("express");
var router = express.Router();

router.get("/registerRequest/:user", function(req, res, next){
    console.log("response for param");
    console.log(req.params.user);
});

router.get("/registerRequest", function(req, res, next){
    console.log("normal response");
    console.log();
});
```

And here's the app:

```
var express = require("express");
var app = express();
app.use("/api", index);
```

Note that these are just small, relevant to the question, portions of the code.

Now, the output in the console is

> normal response

But from my understanding, it should be:

> response for param
>
> user

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the url `/api/registerRequest?user=user`, you are sending user as a query parameter. Which will allow you to access it from `req.query.user`. [more here](http://expressjs.com/en/api.html#req.query)

In order to access it from `req.params.user`, you'll need to change the url in the ajax request to `/api/registerRequest/user`. [doc reference](http://expressjs.com/en/api.html#req.params)

Comment: And if I choose to change the url to: '/api/registerRequest/user', how can I send more params?

Comment: in your route, you will need to specify the parameter `api/registerRequest/:user/:another`. Although it might be simpler to do a POST request if you're planning to set more than 2 properties

Answer (score 2):

You're misunderstanding routing.

`router.get("/registerRequest/:user"` matches URLs of the form `/registerRequest/...`, where `...` becomes `req.params.user`.

You aren't making such a URL.

Comment: so what would be the solution? what should I change to get the desired output

Comment: Check if the expected parameter exists?

Comment: @PeterVC you answered my question above?

Comment: @Emyeminescu: Either make your URL match your route or move your code to the route that matches the URL.